# Rendering a lot of data into the form of Material UI cards is getting very slow and low performances

Tags: reactjs, performance, redux, material-ui, card

I'm building a web application using React, Redux and MUI.

I've a page where i'm showing all the products (approx 8000 products) with MUI card for each (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/). The thing is that it is extremly low to charge. Performances are beyond trash.

I don't have issues when i'm using DATAGRID tho (with the same amount of data).

I don't really know how to approach this issue. Do you have any tips for it ?

Comment: Are you using something like **load on scroll**? Or are you just fetch all at once?

Comment: You need virtualisation you prolly want to use something like this https://tanstack.com/virtual/v3